# mysql get data from both tables with single statment

Tags: mysql

TABLE USERS

```
usrid names country city
------------------------

1    john doe   uk   landon   
2    jane deo   uk   landon
```

TABLE MSG

```
msg_id msg_from msg_to
----------------------


1      ID 1      ID 2
```

NOW - EXAMPLE

```
msg_id msg_from                                                         msg_to
----------------------


1      ID 1 from tbl USERS - get names for this ID from table users     ID 2 from tbl USERS - get names for this ID from table users
```

how can i get names by selecting from table msg and get names from table users with single mysql statement 
its like joining

Comment: You get data like the table rows are joining by... joining.

Answer (score 0):

So JOINs work like:

```
SELECT msg_id, msgfrom.name AS msg_from, msgto.name AS msg_to
FROM MSG
JOIN USERS msgfrom ON msg_from = msgfrom.usrid
JOIN USERS msgto ON msg_to = msgto.usrid
```